# add jpanel from method to jframe

Tags: java, swing, jframe, return, jpanel

In my project I have some classes. One class to create the gui, except of the JFrame.
I will create the JFrame in my Main class such as:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class KodeHusker {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            JFrame f = new JFrame();
            f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            f.add(new JLabel("test"));
            f.add(new GUI().viewProgram());//it works fine, when i remove this
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.pack();
            f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            f.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
}
```

the gui class is where I create all the gui, and the viewProgram method is declared as:

```
public JPanel viewProgram(){}
```

which returns a JPanel.

As the comment in the code tells, when I remove that line it all works fine, but when I have it, the JFrame never shows, although there aren't any exceptions. The shortcut to close the program doesn't work neither.

Anybody who has an idea of what i'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advise.

Comment: You're probably showing us the wrong code since I'll bet the problem is in viewProgram() or in your GUI's constructor. I suspect that you've got an infinite loop going on there or in some other way are stomping on the Swing event thread otherwise known as the EDT or event dispatch thread.

As an aside, I like that you're trying to avoid extending Swing GUI components unnecessarily. That is a good thing to strive for.

Comment: Check for empty exception handlers.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, yes, you were right. After a closer look, I found an while-statement without an end, in viewProgram().

Comment: Ah good. Even a blind squirrel will find a nut every now and then. Glad you've got it fixed!

Answer (score 0):

here is what a jPanel should look like, not sure (can see your code?)

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class JPanelExt extends JPanel  implements Runnable {
private int xCoor = 50;
private boolean moving = false;

 public JPanelExt() {       
      //Thread 
          thread = new Thread (this);       //
          thread.start();   }   

  public void paintComponent (Graphics g)
     {  
            super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawString("DVC 10.0",xCoor,30);  
            g.drawRect(50, 50, 200,100);    
            g.drawOval(50,50,200,100);  
}   
    @Override
public void run() {
while (true)
        {   
    if (moving==true)
                   {    
          this.xCoor = this.xCoor+10;
        if (xCoor > this.getWidth())
                             {  
            xCoor = 0;      
                       }
            this.repaint(); 
               }        
        try {
            Thread.sleep(50);
        }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {    
        e.printStackTrace();            
                    }   
   }    
   public void setMoving(boolean moving) 
       {    
            this.moving = moving;   
        }
}
```